# Am I wrong when I think that I can hear the two different ways they pronounce "flap T"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english, phonetics, flapping

When I listen to the Beatles' "LET IT BE", I can distinctly hear that the first T is pronounced like Polish or Russian or Spanish "R", only more quickly and softer. But when I watch "The Negative Reaction" episode from COLUMBO TV series, I can distinctly hear that when Lorna says "Mrs Peterson", her "T" is pronounced like Polish or Russian or Spanish "D", not "R". I asked my Tennessee friend about it and he says that he hears no differences. But I hear the differences! Even that edition of Advanced Oxford dictionary that I own says that "it is like a brief /d/ or the r-sound...". That is the dictionary implies that there can be two versions of flap-t. But all Canadian and American students I ask about it say that they see no difference. Can native British English-speakers tell me if I am right when saying that I see the differences in pronouncing this FLAP T.

For example, Abba pronounces "D" in "waiting" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZ7C127Q-GY. But they pronounce Polish/Russian "R" in "takes it all" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyIOl-s7JTU

Comment: We’d need sound recordings to answer whether the two particular instances you're talking about are different. But flapped /t/ (like all other sounds) can vary in its exact pronunciation, and yes, both [d] and [ɾ] are possible values depending on context, speed of speech, dialect, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Janus Bahs Jacquet, for you immediate answer. I have just edited my question to give links to some recordings.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I may be completely off, but I’m guessing by the way the asker has used phonemic slashes instead of phonetic brackets here, combined with how they’ve clustered [several kinds of ever-so-slightly different coronal flaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental,_alveolar_and_postalveolar_flaps) in their question, suggests to me that they may have a broader classification in mind here than would necessarily apply with exact pronunciations. Wide variations in realization lead to virtually infinite allophones, depending on how many digits of precision your measuring tool has.

Comment: Relevant post on John Wells’s phonetic blog: [tap, tap](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2012/08/tap-tap.html)

Comment: bit weird to use abba as an example being non natives with accents that show it, but if it illustrates your point why not I suppose...

Comment: There are all sorts of subtleties in English pronunciation, and often minor differences between different local cultures, or even between two pronunciations of the same word by the same person, depending on context and tone.  It's not at all unexpected that native English speakers have learned how to ignore these differences, at an objective level, even though they are often sensitive to their subjective implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments from Janus Bahs Jacquet and tchrist, there is bound to be a range of variations in the way flapped T is pronounced, which could be regional, social or idiosyncratic to a particular speaker.

In terms of standard forms of English, flapped-T is primarily an American phenomenon (it also occurs in Australian English and some regional accents of England and Ireland). It must be borne in mind that, whilst The Beatles (Paul McCartney, at least) and Abba undoubtedly sang with American-influenced pronunciation, neither group was from the USA, so their pronunciation was almost certainly influenced to some extent by their native accent/language.

Comment: And it should further be noted that in very many cases the pronunciations of song lyrics are often not the pronunciations that even those singers would use in normal speech, but rather they have been modified to suit the song.